# Не работает Wi-fi и Bluetooth одновременно на UBUNTU 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

Когда я подключаю по Bluetooth любое устройство, при этом у меня есть подключение к интернету, буквально через 1-2 минуты, начинаются сильные тормоза и wi-fi начинает реконнектиться.

**Network Controller:**
Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)

**UBUNTU 20.04 LTS**

**UPD:** Данная проблема возникает имеенно на этой ОС,ранее использовал ОС WINDOWS 10, таких проблем не наблюдалось вовсе

Comment: `Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)` — это всё «бла-бла-бла». vid:pid посмотрите у адаптера (`$ lspci -nn`, пример искомого: `1969:1091`), и гуглите по этой паре, добавив ещё пару ключевых слов: «wifi bluetooth» (ну, ещё для конкретики: «linux» или «ubuntu»).

Comment: Почитайте https://itumnik.ru/wifi/naushniki-tormozit-internet , https://forum.ixbt.com/topic.cgi?id=14:62244

Comment: В почти всех моделях ноутов есть электрические линии-сигналы для взаимной блокировки передатчиков, что бы два передатчика не давали сигнал в эфир одновременно. Так как повторить это "изобретение" довольно сложно, попробуте просто разнести устройства или антены друг от друга хотя бы сантиметров на 30, а лучше больше, удлиннив USB шнуром-удлинителем. Передатчики могут просто взаимо-глушить друг-друга. (P.S. вероятнее всего это физика, физику не исправишь програмно)

Comment: Не тестировал решения на ноутах и решения wifi+bt в одном корпусе. По идее такие решения должны давать лучше результат. В сети так же рекомендуют перейти на диапазон wifi 5Ghz

Comment: Возможно 10-ка програмно блокирует драйвера (менее сек блокировка) таким образом, что бы передача непроисходила по WiFi и Bt одновременно, а под линуксом это не реализовали по какой-то причине.